# how to search for *.avi files in android?

Tags: android

How to get a list of files, say ending with .avi , that are on the users SD card?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use FileFilter for scanning the .avi files from sdcard. like:

```
 //Check media mounted or not
 if(Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(Environment.getExternalStorageState()))
 {
 File sdCardDir=new File("/sdcard");
 File sdCardDir=Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
 ArrayList<File>files=getFiles(file);

 private ArrayList<File> getFiles(Filefile){
 File files[]=sdCardDir.listFiles(filter);

 for(File f:files){
     if(f.isDirectory()&&f.canRead()){
     getFiles(f);
     }else if(f.isFile()){
     videlList.add(f);
 }
 } 
 //USE FileFilter 
 FileFilter filter=new FileFilter(){
 @Override
 public boolean accept(File f){
 return f.isDirectory()||f.getName().matches("^.*?//.(avi)$");
 }  
 }
```